# Are votes in electronic voting machines always manually counted?

Tags: united-states, electronic-voting

I would like a clarification about how the system works, because I always thought that votes cast in electronic machines a) left a paper trail and b) were always manually verified.

My idea was that electronic voting machines would be useful for several reason:

- Fast "first count" of votes in election day.
- Less confusion (e.g. "butterfly ballots") for the voters and less void votes.
- Less chance of unintentional void votes (e.g. people putting two ballots in the envelope, or ballots improperly filled)
- Easier for handicapped people (e.g. would allow to connect headphones for blind people)
- Signal possible issues with the process (e.g. if the machine computed results differ significantly from the manually computed results).

But after reading about some claims (**which are off-topic for this question**), there is a request for a manual recount of several countries with electronic polling stations, and from what I read it sounds like electronic voting results were not manually verified in the first place.

Am I right or wrong? Are machine results always verified manually or not?

Comment: Not all electronic voting machines have a paper trail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like everything else with elections, this varies state-by-state.  [This page](https://ballotpedia.org/Voting_methods_and_equipment_by_state) has a list of what kind of machine each state uses (more detailed and up-to-date map [here](https://www.verifiedvoting.org/verifier/#)), but there are effectively five kinds:

- **Optical Scan** - Just like standardized testing: Voter marks the ballot, then a machine scans it and counts it.
- **Direct Recording Electronic (DRE)** - Voter enters their vote directly on the machine, and the machine records it.  There's two broad subtypes here:

  - **Voter Verified Paper Trail** - Some DREs print out a paper receipt which the voter can visually confirm is correct (or void if not).
  - **No paper trail** - Other DREs provide no confirmation.  The *only* record is in the machine's memory.
- **Ballot Marking Devices** - Voter enters their vote directly on the machine, and the machine generates a physical ballot which is the actual vote.
- **Punch Card** - Voter punches holes in a card, which then is scanned by a machine or hand-counted.

No state that I'm aware of does *not* use the auto-calculated totals for reporting the results from the state.  However, 29 states (plus D.C.) require a [post-election audit](http://www.ncsl.org/research/elections-and-campaigns/post-election-audits635926066.aspx#state%20req's) of some portion of the vote, to verify that the results seem accurate. For the most part, these audits are hand counts.

Obviously, there's no way to hand recount a DRE with no paper trail.  Unfortunately, there are five states that used this type of machine exclusively this year, and another ten that used it in part (usually a large part).  At least [in Pennsylvania](http://billypenn.com/2016/11/23/a-pennsylvania-recount-for-hillary-clinton-a-nightmare-scenario-explained/), officials don't consider this to be much of a problem because there's no centralized electronic counting - to broadly affect the election, you'd have to physically hack each machine in question.  There's still no way to verify the results, though.